# How to create a ModelFormset to edit certain fields of an unsaved model?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, forms, django-forms

In my django app I receive multiple rows of data from a server. After reception I ask the user to give each data row a name and to decide whether to sync the row in the future or not. Afterwards I save this information in the database along with the rows.

This means I have the model

```
class Row(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 191)
    synced = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    col_1 = models.CharField(max_length = 191)
    ...
    col_n = models.CharField(max_length = 191)
```

and the form

```
class RowForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Row
        fields = ['name','synced']
```

In my template I want to display "name" and "synced" as form fields and "col_1",...,"col_n" as not editable data in a row.

In my view:

I received the data from the server and created Row model instances from it. *Here is where the shit starts to get ugly.* I try to define a ModelFormset. But wait a minute: I do not have a QuerySet to feed to it, since the data is not in the database yet, although it is in a model instance.

Ok. Maybe I should use a regular Formset then. But wait: I do not want to feed any initial data to the Formset. The form fields schould be empty/their default value. Since I can not "preserve" the "col_1",...,"col_n" data in the formset without making it editable, I have to pass it as a seperate object in the context. I have to `render()` the template with

```
context={'row_formset': row_formset, 'row_data': row_data}
```

and I have to preserve the "col_1",...,"col_n" in the session, since it will not be included in the POST data. That is a pain in the ass, but ok...

But wait a minute: If I iterate over the formset rows in the template, how can I simulatniously iterate over the data rows to display them in the same row alongside? I can not zip them together in the context, since one is a formset and I need the management form.

Hell, this is ugly.

What is the "correct", most "djangoish" way to accomplish this?

Example sketch:
[image: sketch]

Comment: It is not very clear to me what exactly you want. Perhaps it could help if you make some sort of "sketch" that shows what you are looking for. You can set fields to `readonly` in your `RowForm`, and the `Form` will also prevent that POST data will change the elements (at least since Django-2.0 iirc).

Comment: I added a sketch

Comment: well I think you do not need to `zip` here, you can just use `form.instance` to get access to the instance of that specific form. So you can iterate over the forms in your `formset`, and render the other columns with `form.instance.col_1` for example.

Comment: Do regular Formsets have `form.instance`? It appearently does not make sense to use a ModelFormset, since the data is not in the database yet

Comment: no the `form`s *in* a `FormSet`. In essence a `FormSet` is not much more than a collection of forms with some logic to redirect the data to the proper form.

Comment: I thought only ModelForms in a ModelFomset have those. Could you write me an answer, using the data I provided in the sketch? Or link me to some documentation which teaches me how to initialize the formset correctly an use the form.instance